# Circular radio options with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I need to design options for color as in the following picture.

[image: link]

By default, each option is a button filled with the color itself. When it is chosen, an additional thin circular line would cover outside the option. How could it be achieved in React?

Comment: thank @silentw for editing the post

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you can show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the custom radio and other element on below link.

[Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892171/create-a-custom-radio-button-using-react-js)

Comment: this one is for react-native which is not related to my current work

Comment: Check out this then will be helpful --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892171/create-a-custom-radio-button-using-react-js